# Multiple line out put, with multiple variables using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I've got a couple of forms on HTML giving a variable to each other. My plan is to show a sort of "receipt" to display what is being purchased.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Review Purchases</p>
<p id="recipt"></p>
<button onClick="refresh()" type="button">Refresh</button>
<p><a href="Payment.html">PAY NOW</a></p>
    
</body>
<script>
    greenglovess = localStorage.getItem("greengloves");
    blackglovess = localStorage.getItem("blackgloves");
    whiteglovess = localStorage.getItem("whitegloves");
    redglovess = localStorage.getItem("redgloves");
    
    
    function refresh(){
        document.getElementById("recipt").innerHTML =
            "Green Gloves: " + greenglovess +
            "Black Gloves: " + blackglovess +
            "White Gloves: " + whiteglovess +
            "Red Gloves: " + redglovess;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

How can I make it so that the gloves will be displayed on separate lines?

The Important Stuff:

```
<script>
    greenglovess = localStorage.getItem("greengloves");
    blackglovess = localStorage.getItem("blackgloves");
    whiteglovess = localStorage.getItem("whitegloves");
    redglovess = localStorage.getItem("redgloves");


    function refresh(){
        document.getElementById("recipt").innerHTML =
            "Green Gloves: " + greenglovess +
            "Black Gloves: " + blackglovess +
            "White Gloves: " + whiteglovess +
            "Red Gloves: " + redglovess;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Quickest solution would be to append a `<br>`. "Green Gloves: " + greenglovess + "<br>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `<br/>` tag to add a newline in HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Review Purchases</p>
  <p id="recipt"></p>
  <button onClick="refresh()" type="button">Refresh</button>
  <p><a href="Payment.html">PAY NOW</a></p>

</body>
<script>
  greenglovess = localStorage.getItem("greengloves");
  blackglovess = localStorage.getItem("blackgloves");
  whiteglovess = localStorage.getItem("whitegloves");
  redglovess = localStorage.getItem("redgloves");


  function refresh() {
    document.getElementById("recipt").innerHTML =
      "Green Gloves: " + greenglovess + "<br/>" +
      "Black Gloves: " + blackglovess + "<br/>" +
      "White Gloves: " + whiteglovess + "<br/>" +
      "Red Gloves: " + redglovess;
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

See [Multiline Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#multi-line_strings):

> Any newline characters inserted in the source are part of the template literal.

```js
console.log(`string text line 1
string text line 2`);
```